# Що правильніше вживати: "швидко" чи "скоро" в сучасній мові?

Tags: вживання-слів

Словники реєструють обидва варіанти, до того ж, зараз спостерігається розмежування (дещо штучне, як на мене) - вживати "швидко" для опису дії, а "скоро" - для опису часу. Хоч для означення часу в більшості випадків можна вжити "незабаром".

Наприклад: [Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53409/26363.html)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на Ukrainian.SE! Al Crow, чи могли б ви навести приклади (з посиланнями) розмежування у вживанні швидко/скоро, яке ви помічаєте?

Answer (score 2):

Як пише Чак Євгенія Давидівна, український мовознавець, у [Літературному місті](http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=21278):

> "За сучасними словниками прислівник *скоро* вживається в двох значеннях: по-перше, для вираження **інтенсивності руху**, по-друге – в часовому значенні – з відтінком **«через деякий час»**. Отже, за словниками виходить, що слово *скоро* своїми значеннями в основному не відрізняється від слова *швидко*. Проте останнім часом у мовній практиці норми стилістичного вживання обох прислівників починають викристалізовуватися в той спосіб, що *скоро* здебільшого виступає як прислівник із часовим значенням (як синонім до *незабаром*, *невдовзі*), а *швидко* – як прислівник, що виражає інтенсивність руху. В цьому можна переконатися на численних прикладах в художньої літератури.
>    У О. Гончара: «Угорець заходив до неї з різних боків, хижо націлявся і цюкав. Колода тільки перекочувалася з місця на місце, ціла-цілісінька. Бійці чмихали. Невдалий дроворуб скоро впрів. Хаєцький не міг далі байдуже дивитись на його самокатування. Він кинув батіжок, плюнув у долоні.» 
>   У М. Стельмаха: «Будьте милостиві [до землемірів], скажіть, чи скоро будете нам наділяти землю?»
>   Слово *швидко* з виразним значенням інтенсивності дії виступає в творах дореволюційних і радянських письменників. Ось кілька прикладів. «А воно молоде, то швидко і виходилося собі…» (Марко Вовчок). «Василина вибігла із зали так швидко, як і вбігла» (І. Нечуй-Левицький)."

Отже Ви абсолютно вірно зауважили про дане розмежування. Але пані Євгенія додала ще ремарку:

> "Доцільність семантичного розрізнення цих слів диктується потребами мовного життя, яке прагне смислової точності. **Правда, іноді контекст дозволяє вжити будь-яке з двох слів, і зміст речення лишається незмінним.** Наприклад, у реченні «Хто з всіми добрий хоче буть, той *швидко* втратить добрий путь» (І. Франко). Слово *швидко* без шкоди для змісту можна замінити словом *скоро*. А от у прикладі з Панаса Мирного замість *швидко* безперечно краще було б вжити слово *скоро* («Од купи до купи знай бігав Карпо і гукав: «Піддержте, братця! Що се таке? За бісовими думками *швидко* не можна буде бідному чоловікові й дихнути»), бо формально виходить, що йдеться про частоту дихання (можна буде, мовляв, тільки повільно дихати), а не про час, коли це настане («незабаром»). Звичайно, в розмовній мові можуть виникати ще виразніші двозначності. Тому треба помітити порух мови до розрізнення слів *швидко* і *скоро* і зважити на вироблення такої тенденції."

**Отже, як виявилось, все залежить від контексту в якому будуть зустрічатись ці слова. Але у розмовній українській *швидко* частіше буде використовуватись для вираження інтенсивності руху, а *скоро* — як прислівник з часовим значенням**.

Comment: Мені здається, ця тенденція прослідковується через багаторічне зближення із самізнаєтеякою мовою.